# Is the product of countable metrizable spaces with box-topology still metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

I am currently working on product and box topology.

Textbook has given an example:'$R^{\omega}$ is not metrizable with box-topology.

So I have a suppose:

If X is metrizable, will $X^{\omega}$ be metrizable?

Even more strict, if $X_{\alpha}$ is metrizable for each $\alpha$, will the countable product of $X_{\alpha}$ metrizable with box-topology?

Comment: Which part of your textbook's argument for $\Bbb R$ does not work for a generic metric $X$?

Comment: Fun fact: it's (AFAIK) still an open problem whether $\Bbb R^\omega$ is normal. (We do know it's not hereditarily normal, as shown by van Douwen.)

Comment: The textbook gave an example as (-$\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{1}{n}$), which does not satisify a common space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma as far as I know it's known under CH by an old result of Rudin but it's open in general

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I know, but there are several spaces that are normal under CH and non-normal under MA and $\lnot$CH. This could be one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if $X$ is any non-discrete metric space, $X^\omega$ in the box topology will **not** be first countable, so in particular not metrisable.

Sketch of proof: let $p \in X$ be a non-isolated point and pick a local base $U_n$ which obeys $\overline{U_{n+1}} \subsetneq U_n$ for all $n$ and then prove (via a diagonal argument) that $(p,p,p,\ldots)$ does *not* have a countable local base in $X^\omega$. For more info on box products, see the chapter about them in the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology. You can also see there that $X^\omega$ will rarely be compact, connected and many other nice properties. It's a rarely used topology for that reason, except to construct examples.

Comment: How to make sure the existence of the local base which obeys the rule? I can only see $U_1\supset U_2 \supset...$

Comment: @yLccc This is easy: take any countable local base and make it decreasing in the standard way. Then use $T_3$ to achieve the closure part.